# CXF Code First SOAP Web Service Endpoint Protocol

Tags: web-services, soap, cxf, code-first

I am implementing a Code first cxf web service. How does cxf decide the `soap:address` part of generated wsdl ? Is it using the hostname from the deployed machine ?

Also, can I change the endpoint protocol from http to https programmatically or by-configuration on the deployed application ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Spring for this.

you must create an impl for the interface service.

```java
@WebService(endpointInterface = "com.services.MyAwesomeService")
public class MyAwesomeServiceImpl implements MyAwesomeService {

    @Override
    public String sayHi(String text) {
        return "Hello " + text;
    }    

}
```

And config vía Spring.

```java
@Configuration
public class ServiceConfig {

    @Bean(name = Bus.DEFAULT_BUS_ID)
    public SpringBus springBus() {
        return new SpringBus();
    }   

    @Bean(name = "myAwesomeService")
    public MyAwesomeServiceImpl myAwesomeService() {
        return new MyAwesomeServiceImpl();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public Endpoint endpoint() {
        EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(springBus(), myAwesomeService());
        endpoint.publish("/MyAwesomeService");
        
        return endpoint;
    }
}
```

After doing this. You will have your service published in the path `/MyAwesomeService`.

To configure the HTTPS protocol, I recommend you configure it in the application container (Tomcat) or dedicated front (Apache, F5, etc.)